# why does my content box does not work properly in this expand function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have some trouble styling the content box (verticalslider_contents) of this expand div, and i want that this box to have border, and to have a dynamic height ( to be as high as it is the text in it ) . I know i have to use clear the float, but i do not know why it does not work. Can you help me? For this i use jquery expand function as you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/DaUNb/

**html**

```
<div class="verticalslider" id="textExample">
        <ul class="verticalslider_tabs">
            <li><a href="#">Activitate 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Praesent Pulvinar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nunc Adipiscing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Praesent Dapibus</a></li>                        
        </ul>
        <ul class="verticalslider_contents">
            <li>
            <h2>Activitate 1</h2>
            <p>DADA ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan placerat bibendum. Etiam ut nunc sed purus tempus varius. Donec id magna massa, posuere consectetur neque. Mauris tortor lacus, iaculis a pulvinar luctus, lobortis vel velit. In elementum lorem eu felis fermentum placerat et sit amet ligula. Integer euismod augue eu massa tincidunt consectetur. Suspendisse potenti. Donec in enim sollicitudin enim dignissim imperdiet ut et dolor. Phasellus nec risus vel nunc hendrerit auctor. Sed rhoncus sapien at nisl aliquam luctus. </p>
             <p>DADA ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan placerat bibendum. Etiam ut nunc sed purus tempus varius. Donec id magna massa, posuere consectetur neque. Mauris tortor lacus, iaculis a pulvinar luctus, lobortis vel velit. In elementum lorem eu felis fermentum placerat et sit amet ligula. Integer euismod augue eu massa tincidunt consectetur. Suspendisse potenti. Donec in enim sollicitudin enim dignissim imperdiet ut et dolor. Phasellus nec risus vel nunc hendrerit auctor. Sed rhoncus sapien at nisl aliquam luctus. </p>
             <p>DADA ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan placerat bibendum. Etiam ut nunc sed purus tempus varius. Donec id magna massa, posuere consectetur neque. Mauris tortor lacus, iaculis a pulvinar luctus, lobortis vel velit. In elementum lorem eu felis fermentum placerat et sit amet ligula. Integer euismod augue eu massa tincidunt consectetur. Suspendisse potenti. Donec in enim sollicitudin enim dignissim imperdiet ut et dolor. Phasellus nec risus vel nunc hendrerit auctor. Sed rhoncus sapien at nisl aliquam luctus. </p>

            </li>
            <li>
                <p>blabla</p>
            </li>
            <li>
            <h2>Nunc Adipiscing</h2>
            <p>CUC adipiscing purus id orci rutrum placerat. Nam posuere elementum ipsum quis faucibus. Fusce fermentum turpis ac erat mollis sit amet varius mi placerat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut ante justo, varius quis dignissim nec, condimentum in dui. Nulla sed lectus eu nunc vehicula vulputate vel nec velit. Integer eu purus nunc. Donec odio augue, sagittis pellentesque adipiscing id, dignissim vel enim. Maecenas a risus est.</p></li>
            <li>
            <h2>Praesent Dapibus</h2>
            <p>Praesent dapibus metus vitae velit blandit tempor. Donec dignissim tempus neque, a vestibulum massa aliquam sed. Vestibulum velit quam, facilisis vel pharetra nec, bibendum eget mauris. In vitae ligula ac justo varius ullamcorper. Nullam vitae urna eu metus pellentesque vehicula vel sit amet nibh. Cras nec velit dictum neque imperdiet congue in nec eros. Suspendisse ante felis, eleifend sed pellentesque id, sagittis ut magna. .</p></li>                        
        </ul>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

and css

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* Container */
.verticalslider {
/*border: 1px solid #666666;*/
overflow: hidden; 
width:1000px;
margin-top: 25px; 
height: 100%; 
}

/* Tabs */
.verticalslider_tabs {
float: left;
width: 220px;
}
.verticalslider_tabs li{ 
border-left:1px solid #666666;
}

.verticalslider_tabs, .verticalslider_tabs li{
margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}
.verticalslider_tabs li{
list-style-type: none;
}

.verticalslider_tabs a:link, .verticalslider_tabs a:visited{
display: block; 
width: 200px; 
height: 29px; 
padding: 14px 10px 6px 10px; 
background: url(../img/tab-activitati/tabBG.jpg) bottom repeat-x;  
background-color: #eeeeee;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
font-size: 20px; 
font-weight: bold;
color: #333333;  
border-right: 1px solid #666666; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #666666; 
text-decoration: none;
}

.verticalslider_tabs a:hover, .verticalslider_tabs a:active{ 
background: url(../img/tab-activitati/tabHoverBG.jpg) bottom repeat-x; 
background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.verticalslider_tabs li:first-child a:link, .verticalslider_tabs li:first-child a:visited{
border-top: 1px solid #666666;
 height: 30px;
 }

.verticalslider_tabs .activeTab a:link, .verticalslider_tabs .activeTab a:visited{
background: #ffffff; 
border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.verticalslider_tabs .activeTab a:hover, .verticalslider_tabs .activeTab a:active{
background: #ffffff; 
border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.verticalslider .arrow {
background: url(../img/tab-activitati/arrow.png); 
width: 27px; 
height: 60px; 
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1000; 
margin-left: 220px; 
margin-top: -55px; 
}

/* Contents */
.verticalslider_contents{
float: left;
width: 750px;
display: inline; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
border: 1px solid #666666;
height:100%;
}
.verticalslider_contents li{
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
width: 750px;
padding: 0px;
display: none;
position: absolute;
list-style-type: none; 
}
.verticalslider_contents li h2{
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif, font-size: 15px; 
color: #333333;margin: 5px 20px; 
padding: 0px;
}

.verticalslider_contents li p{ 
margin: 5px 20px; 
padding: 0px;
color: #333333;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
font-size: 13px; 
}

.verticalslider_contents .activeContent{
display: inline;
}

#clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling for `.verticalslider_contents li` makes it `position: absolute`, which isn't the best option if you want the height to fit the content. Changing this to `position:relative` seems to fix the problem, and we add `overflow:auto` to make the scrollbar visible when needed:

```
.verticalslider_contents li {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: initial !important;
    min-height: 200px !important;
}

.verticalslider_contents .activeContent {
    display: block;
}
```

Which uses the `min-height` attribute to set the minimum height of the content to be the height of the tab container. The `height: initial !important` attribute overrides jQuery's styling of `height: 208px` (why this is here I do not know), to be the height of the content.

I've also changed the `display` attribute for the `.activeContent` to `block` so that it follows these height changes. Note that the original `inline` property does not allow you to specify height.

New JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DaUNb/2/

Comment: i like the idea, but it is not what i was searching... maybe i was not clear : the CONTENT box should be as high as the height of all tabs if it contains short text, and if i add a long text to be as high as it needs to be to fit the whole text. For example, if i click on the first tab ( and the content has only 1 short sentence) the content box will be as big as the total height of the tabs on the left, instead if i click on the second and there are 10 pharagraph , i want that the content box will expand as high as it needs to fit all that 10 pharagraphs.So how can i do this?

Comment: I noticed JQuery tries to change the height, so added a few `!important` tags, and also a few other attributes to get the effect you wanted. see the edited answer

Comment: I have only 1 last question, why when i change tabs, is there like the text wants to be down and then comes up ? it feels like a bug, even if it works...

Comment: I would guess it's the JQuery animation.

Comment: if you could help me, i do not find anything wrong. I would apreciate that :)

Comment: Actually, just figured it out. Because I made the content blocks `position: relative`, when you navigate the previous content block goes below. I make a few quick fixes to the positioning, and added a few !important tags: http://jsfiddle.net/DaUNb/3/

Comment: actually got another problem :)), i think is the jquery problem, when i run the page it shows me the 3rd tab, not the first one, why?

Comment: Just change `activeIndex` to `0`, that should do the trick.
http://jsfiddle.net/DaUNb/4/